# Calculating Required Torque

Tags: motor, motion, torque, wheel

Say I had an object with 4 motors/wheels attached (in a fairly standard arrangement).

I need to calculate the amount of torque required from the motors to be able to move the object of x kilograms consistently (without skipping any steps) at a velocity of y, travelling up a slope of angle z.

I'm guessing this would also depend on factors like the grip of the tyre and such?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a standard dynamics problem. Let's use this figure I drew:

[image: Corrected car going up incline.]

Some definitions:

$$
\begin{align}
m & \mbox{, the mass of the vehicle in kg.} \\
\mu_{\mbox{rolling}} & \mbox{, the rolling friction coefficient of your tires.} \\
\theta & \mbox{, the incline of the plane in radians.}\\
g & \mbox{, the gravitational constant, 9.81 } m/s^2 \\
r_{\mbox{tire}} & \mbox{, the radius of the tire in m.}
\end{align}
$$

The normal force of the vehicle against the incline is going to be
$$
f_{\mbox{normal}} = mg \cos{\theta} \\
$$
The normal force is going to play into your frictional force in that 
$$
f_{\mbox{friction}} = \mu_{\mbox{rolling}} f_{\mbox{normal}} \\
$$

The force opposing the vehicle, trying to cause it to roll down the slope, is
$$
f_{\mbox{opposing}} = m g \sin{\theta} \\
$$

Now, keep in mind that the opposing force and the frictional forces are both *at the point of contact between the wheel and the surface*. Also note that frictional coefficients are constant for a given force [regardless of contact surface area](http://www.physlink.com/Education/AskExperts/ae140.cfm), so as long as all four tires are equal and evenly loaded, you don't need to worry about the per-tire information **yet**.

So, you have your forces to overcome; opposing and friction. Now you need to convert those to torques:

$$
\tau = f r_{\mbox{tire}} \sin{\phi} 
$$

Where here I've used $\phi$ to help distinguish between the applied force angle and the incline angle $\theta$. Anyways, the force is being applied at a right angle, $\sin{90} = 1$, so you can leave that term off and you're left with

$$
\begin{align}
\tau_{\mbox{ losses}} &= (f_{\mbox{opposing}} + f_{\mbox{rolling friction}}) r_{\mbox{tire}} \\
 &= (mg( \sin{\theta}+\cos{\theta}  \mu_{\mbox{rolling}})) r_{\mbox{tire}} \\
\end{align}
$$

Now your speed comes into play, with the formula:

$$
P_{\mbox{rotating}} = \tau_{\mbox{applied}} \omega \\
$$ 
where $P_{\mbox{rotating}}$ is the rotational power output in Watts, $\tau_{\mbox{applied}}$ is the torque applied in Nm, and $\omega$ is the rotational velocity in rad/s. Your vehicle's linear speed, in $\frac{m}{s}$, is given by:

$$
v = r_{\mbox{tire}} \omega \\
$$
so
$$
\omega = \frac{v}{r_{\mbox{tire}}} \\
$$

Putting it all together:

$$
\begin{align}
P_{\mbox{rotating}} &= (mg (\sin{\theta} + \cos{\theta} \mu_{\mbox{rolling}})) r_{\mbox{tire}} \frac{v}{r_{\mbox{tire}}} \\
 &= v m g(\sin{\theta} +\cos{\theta} \mu_{\mbox{rolling}})) \\
\end{align}
$$

Now, finally, this is the rotating power required to move the entire vehicle. At this point, however many (equally sized and loaded) tires you use needs to contribute a corresponding fraction of this power; 4 tires = each one needs to deliver at least 1/4 of the power given above.

Comment: @Bending Unit 22 - thanks for the edit. I'm still new to Latex.

Comment: [This is a nice reference on math meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: sinθ changes to cosθ at the end here, is this a mistake, or am I missing something? Protating=(mgsinθ(1+μrolling))rtirevrtire=vmg(sinθ+cosθμrolling))

Comment: @Alec Dorrington - you are correct. I revised the equation. Sorry I normally post from my phone so the equations can get a little muddled on my end.